# Docker status Exited (2)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to use a docker but I got some troubles with that.

docker-compose :

```yaml
    version: '3.7'
    
    services:
      web:
        container_name: web
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
          - ./web/:/usr/src/web/
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
          - 3000:3000
          - 5432:9432
        stdin_open: true
        depends_on:
          - db
    
      db:
        container_name: db
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        volumes:
          - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=admin
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
          - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
    
    volumes:
      postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile :

```yaml
    # pull official base image
    FROM python:3.8.3-alpine
    
    # set work directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/web
    
    # set environment variables
    ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    
    # install psycopg2 dependencies
    RUN apk update \
        && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
    
    # install nodejs
    RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
    
    # copy project
    ADD . .
    
    # install dependencies
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I typed `sudo docker-compose up -d --build` and the container was successfully created but when I type that :

`docker ps -a`

I got that :

```
    ecf4382327f2        myservice_web             "python manage.py ru…"   34 seconds ago      Exited (2) 33 seconds ago                       web
    97e742aa2f32        postgres:12.0-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   35 seconds ago      Up 34 seconds               5432/tcp            db
```

I don't understand why I got the status `Exited (2)`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Here is my tree

[image: tree]

Comment: Please run and share `docker logs web`

Comment: I got that : `python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: That looks like your answer. I might be missing it but I can't see you putting manage.py into the image in your Dockerfile - maybe it's as simple as that. Hope so

Comment: Can you try `ADD ./* /usr/src/web/` instead of `ADD . .`

Comment: Thanks but I for me there is the file manage.py no ? I put a copy of the tree, could you tell me if for you it is okay ? Thank you a lot !

Comment: I tried `ADD ./* /usr/src/web/` I got the same error

Comment: Can you try to change `command: python /usr/src/web/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` instead of  `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: I got the same error :/

Comment: Do you know if I can see the file in the container ?

Comment: The `volumes:` are hiding the `ADD` commands the Dockerfile does, and if the host-filesystem layout doesn't exactly match what the Dockerfile assembles, you'll get inconsistent results.  Does removing the `volumes:` help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer :

Replacing this `- ./web/:/usr/src/web/` by `- .:/usr/src/web/`